# Mouse Driver suddenly has access to mouse while logged off

Tags: windows-10, mouse, logitech-mouse

Before, whenever I lock my computer, my mouse( logitech g300) would switch to profiles in its built-in memory, but now it still accesses the ones on my computer.

I've not done anything noteworthy for this change to occur. This happened about  2 days ago.

It is my( limited) understanding that Windows intentionally blocks access to certain hardware while locked, so this is quite anomalous to me.

I ask for opinion on possible causes to this and any probability of security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse still needs to function while the computer is logged off, so your assumptions are possibly misapplied.

Things that operate at the user level are inaccessible or non-functional while no user session is logged in. But drivers operate at a lower level, usually SYSTEM, and have access and can operate while no user session is logged in or active.

How Logitech implements its profiles may have changed with a driver update to that profiles operate at the same level as the rest of the driver.

Or, many of these mice store profiles on the mouse itself, and the computer has no say in how or when or whether profiles are switched except via specialized communication via the driver, but the mouse can still switch its own profiles separate from the computer.

I have a Logitech gaming mouse with hardware profile switch buttons, and the profiles have always been able to be switched regardless of whether a user is logged in to the computer or not.

Comment: Just to clarify. On your last paragraph, you are referring to the fact that the driver( or mouse) is able to change where it fetches profile data from regardless of lock status?

To clarify on my end, the mouse works fine regardless of windows login state. While logged out, the mouse inputs are based on the built-in memory; and while logged in, it uses data from whatever the driver gives it( though recently the driver profiles are still used while logged out).

Comment: I don't know details of Logitech's architecture except that I'm assuming profile changes I make in the Logitech utility are loaded into memory on the mouse itself, allowing the mouse to switch profiles whether I'm logged in on the computer or not.